# JQuery Animate to defined position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a webpage that has tabs (currently buttons) along the top and when each one is clicked, it will use the JQuery to animate an expansion of a div container to a specific space in the webpage. Ideally this should be the middle of the screen depending on the size of the final div container size.

The start point should be from under neath the Tabbed button (again, currently a button) but I'm having trouble setting this to animate in correctly.

If I use a relative position, I can't set it to a fixed place such as the middle of the screen. If I used an absolute position, it scrolls in from the top left of the screen rather than from the initial position of the div container.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? My full code is below (only draft as testing ideas first).

Thanks

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#butbut1").click(function(){
            $("#div1").animate({
                left: '250px',
                top: '-50px',
                opacity: '1',
                height: '150px',
                width: '250px'
            });
        });
        $("#butbut2").click(function(){
            $("#div2").animate({
                left: '250px',
                top: '-50px',
                opacity: '1',
                height: '150px',
                width: '250px'
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>

    <button id="butbut1">Start Animation1</button>
    <button id="butbut2">Start Animation2</button>
    <p>Text here, blah blah blah blah</p>

    <div id="div1" style="background:#98bf21;height:0px;width:0px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;opacity:0.5;">Lots of content in here that is much bigger than the actual box, hopefully it doesn't show at first but then it should show later on.</div>
    <div id="div2" style="background:orange;height:0px;width:0px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;opacity:0.5;">Lots of content in here that is much bigger than the actual box, hopefully it doesn't show at first but then it should show later on.</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Made a JSFiddle to show...

https://jsfiddle.net/dyceq9t8/1/

Comment: Understand what you want to achieve, but there are a lot of if/buts with different page sizes, would just a simple set of tabs not do the trick or this is nice. http://tabtab.be/

Comment: @RichardHousham Thanks for the link, but general tabs I'm fine with, its the animation that I'm trying to achieve. Rather than loading different pages which the tabtab is doing, I'm after keeping the info on one page in containers and scrolling through.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value of top in animate() from -50px to some higher value like 100px.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move it in the middle then try by changing this

```
           position:'absolute',
            left: '40%',
            top: '50%',
           margin: '50px 0  0  50px'
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that previously in the JQuery code, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm using the W3Schools Tryit Editor

Comment: hey then add this   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   in the try editor head tag it will work

Comment: Its already there. I think I have found the issue though, I wasn't setting the initial starting point for "Top" in <div> where the style is set.

Comment: add          margin: '50px 0  0  50px'                                                              in the jquery    then   change the top  and left margin value according to your screen position